# syntax error near unexpected token `>' when using '&>>' redirection operator

Tags: bash, shell

At the beggining of my file I redirect stderr to stdout, and stdout to logfile, quick and lazy way to log everything printed.

During my script, some commands have large/unused output and I want to redirect them to my logfile without their output showing on stdout.

I tried to use `/etc/init.d/myservice stop &>> file.log`, but always ending up with the error "... syntax error near unexpected token `>'"

Bash version is 3.2.25(1)-release

Comment: What does the `&>>` operator doing?

Comment: @hek2mgl it redirect both std and err outputs to the file, and append the data

Comment: The duplicate its not what I want. I want to redirect the outpute to logfile, and that its not printed on stdout and stderr. There is no background exec involved

Comment: @Mayerz I see. sorry, missed that

Comment: @hek2mgl No problem

Comment: That syntax wasn't available in 3.2.25, it's a bash 4-ism.  See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/what-is-the-use-of-in-bash)

Comment: @EricRenouf Thanks a lot, I was suspecting it also, but could get my hand on any prooof of this. If you have any workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That syntax wasn't introduced until bash 4.  You can do the same thing though with

```
/etc/init.d/myservice stop >> file.log 2>&1
```

as noted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/what-is-the-use-of-in-bash)

Comment: Perfect, merci beaucoup

Comment: Either MacOS has back ported the feature into bash 3.2 or your answer is wrong. I just saw it working on MacOS with bash 3.2

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm guessing it was back ported then.  [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/make_cmd.c?id=3185942a5234e26ab13fa02f9c51d340cec514f8) is the commit tagged bash-4.0-rc1 that adds the code to `make_cmd.c`

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not sure what you saw, but `&>>` does not work in 3.2.57 that ships with OS X 10.11.6

Comment: @chepner I let a co-worker with a Mac try the command `bash -c 'echo "info" >&1; echo "error" >&2'` executed with a) `1>/dev/null` b) `2>/dev/null` and c) `&>>/dev/null`. Output was as expected. I made sure that he is not using a homebrew version by `bash --version`

Comment: I still claim `bash` 3.2 that ships with OS X does not support `&>>`. Make sure the test itself isn't being run in `zsh` or `bash` 4.x. Does `echo $BASH_VERSION` or `echo $ZSH_VERSION` produce any output?

Comment: @chepner I'm at home now and here is luckily no Mac :) .. I can only say that my co-worker was executing explicitely `bash ...` including `bash --version`.. (I was staying behind him).

Comment: I'm not saying that whatever `bash` is found via path lookup was not `bash` 4.x, but that doesn't mean that whatever terminal emulator he is using is running the same program when it opens a new window. If the test is `bash -c '...' &>>/dev/null`, the `&>>` is not evaluated by the `bash` command being started; it's evaluated by the current shell.

Comment: @chepner Uh, shame on me!! I see what you mean now. I guess it was a zsh then. (The Mac guys love such fancy stuff).