# Issue while logging to file and console/syslog

Tags: bash, logging

I am trying to run user data in bash, and would like to capture output/error in cloudwatch as well as in a local file, as mentioned in the aws link [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data)
However, while exectuing this command:

```
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
```

I get this error msg:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

Any idea what the issue is?
I am using RHEL 8 and bash version is 4.4.20, and I am using #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the file.

If you could suggest a way to do this using just 'logger' is even better, as there seem to be some issue with 'exec' option on my setup.

Thanks!

On the error msg, I refered to multiple questions like these but not much luck:
[Why do I get errors when using > > in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318871/why-do-i-get-errors-when-using-in-bash?rq=3)
[syntax error near unexpected token `>' when using '&>>' redirection operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726784/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-when-using-redirection-operator)
[image]

Comment: I can't get `bash, csh, ksh, sh` to generate that exact error message with your code. I see you include `#!/bin/bash`, but from your cmd like, does `echo $SHELL` provide anything of interest? Good luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a complete, minimal script (i.e. a [mcve]) that reproduces this problem because for all we know the error message is because of a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @shellter, echo $SHELL gives /bin/bash as the response.

Comment: @EdMorton, the issue exists even if my code has just the shebang and the above exec statement. No other line of code exists.

Comment: Great, copy/paste that complete script into your question and then copy/paste the contents of your terminal when you run that script including the output and/or error messages it produces. That would be a [mcve].

Comment: Just now added the screenshot above. Hope it helps.

Comment: I noticed that when i ran the script with 'bash myscript.sh' it ran without the error msg. I am used to running 'sh myscript.sh' and that seem to be an issue.

Comment: Write that up as an answer and accept it after 48 hrs (?) to gain valuable repuration points. Glad you solved your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i was running the script as 'sh myscript.sh'. The script works fine if i run it as 'bash myscript.sh'